# What damage does Legacy of Nightmares work with?

Tags: diablo-iii

For those who don't know, the [Legacy of Nightmare](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-wailing-host) is a ring set that boosts damage by 100%, and reduces damage taken by 4%, for every piece of ancient legendary item equipped. <sub>Patch 2.4.1 at time of writing</sub>

With all ancient gear *(helm, chest, belt, legs, shoulders, bracers, gloves, boots, ammy, 2 rings, and both weapon slots)* this can add up to 1300% damage and 52% damage reduction.

My question is: Does this damage boost apply to **all** sources of damage? The character, his pets and follower, item procs such as [Odyn Son](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/odyn-son) or [Fire Walkers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/fire-walkers) all the legendary gem procs, thorns, bleed, damage gained from items such as [Soul Smasher](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/soulsmasher) and [Death's Bargain](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/deaths-bargain), etc?
Any special exceptions?

I'm hoping for a list of things it will (*or won't, if that is easier*) work with but any information is helpful.

Comment: I don't have time to research now, but LoN definitely boosts all skills (including pets), gems, and thorns (as people are running LoN thorns builds).

Answer (score -1):

It affects all damage the actual character does. Pets and followers aren't included. Legendary procs are affected as they are part of the character.

Comment: How can you explain the existence of "[LoN pet builds](https://www.google.ru/search?q=lon+pet+build)", if pet attacks are not affected?